# Concatenating string and integer fails with "Type mismatch" error

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have the following Inno Setup script, and I'm getting this error on the `SaveStringToFile` line:

> Type Mismatch

Can anybody spot my mistake?

Thank you!

```pascal
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec(
    'open', 'taskkill.exe', '/f /im procterm.exe', '', SW_HIDE,
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);

  SaveStringToFile(
    'c:\program data\myapp\innolog.txt',
    'Error code for procterm was: ' + ErrorCode, True);
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to "sum" a string with a number (an integer):

```pascal
'Error code for procterm was: ' + ErrorCode
```

That's not possible in Pascal/Pascal Script.

You have to convert the number/integer to a string with the [`IntToStr` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_inttostr):

```pascal
'Error code for procterm was: ' + IntToStr(ErrorCode)
```

Or use the [`Format` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format) like:

```pascal
Format('Error code for procterm was: %d', [ErrorCode])
```